# invoke data in the NDSOLVE

Tags: differential-equations

```
 theta = .2;
 sol = NDSolve[{D[g[x, t], t] == x (1 - x) D[g[x, t], x, x]  , g[1, t] == 0, 
 g[0, t] == theta (1 - Exp[-10000000 t]) }, g, {t, 0, 2 }, {x, 0, 1}]
f[x_, t_] := (g /. sol[[1, 1]])[x, t];
t = 0.5;
LogLogPlot[{f[x, t]/(x (1 - x)), 0.2/x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

One initial condition is required to solve the above equation as  g[x, 0]. I do not have the functional form of g[x,0] whereas i have the data for

```
 g[x,0]={19., 5., 4., 3., 3., 1., 3., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} in steps of 0.01 and x varies from 0 to 1.
```

Can I use the values of g[x,0] from the list and invoke into the NDSolve to obtain the final numerical solution.

Comment: You could create an `InterpolatingFunction` and use that.

Comment: Could you please write the commands for this?

Comment: You have second order in x but only gave one boundary condition at x=0

Comment: There are two boundary conditions, one at x=0 and other at x=1 and there is one initial condition too which is given by list g[x,0].

Comment: I did not see `g[1, t] == 0`.  Just an advice. always write the pde on its own, write the BC on its own, and the ic on its own (i.e. on separate lines) and use these later in the call to NDSolve. This always makes things more clear instead of writing everything in one long command.

Comment: Sure, That will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to interpolate g (see @user21 comment)

```
gi = {19., 5., 4., 3., 3., 1., 3., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 
1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.};

tg = Transpose[{Subdivide[0, 1, Length[gi] - 1], gi}];
ipg = Interpolation[tg, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

`ipg[x]` fits the points `tg`!

```
theta = .2;
G = NDSolveValue[{D[g[x, t], t] == x (1 - x) D[g[x, t], x, x], g[1, t] == 0, g[0, t] == theta (1 - Exp[-10000000 t]), g[x, 0] == ipg[x]}, g, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

`G[x,t]`is the solution of your pde